# Android Studio Flutter import corrupted when import organization is triggered

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Running current Dolphin on M1 Mac Mini - Flutter development:

While developing a Flutter app, I added this line of code:

```
log('$drawLastDate - ${draw.day} = ${drawLastDate - draw.day}');
```

Android Studio is comfigured to update imports on inserts so the top line was correctly added by Android Studio:

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
```

I no longer need to log this information so I removed the log line and saved the code change.  Android Studio did this to my imports:

```
'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
```

Anyone else seeing this behaviour or know what I have done to my Android Studio configuratoin?

Comment: It happens a lot of times, not rare, if it's too much, you can try invalidating caches.

Comment: Yes, invalidating seems to have resolved the issue.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes it resolved it but it comes back in a couple of minutes later.

Comment: Try to disable code folding for imports. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000323390/comments/115000294210